# Q: $T$ is a transformation on $\Bbb R^3$ that rotates points about some line through the origin. (help)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with the following question:

Let $A$ be the matrix of the linear transformation $T$. Without writing $A$, find an eigenvalue of $A$ and describe the eigenspace where

$T$ is a transformation on $\Bbb R^3$ that rotates points about some line through the origin.

I would just like some help in understanding what this would look like geometrically. More specifically, what does it mean to rotate a point about some line? (even a picture would be helpful)

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Eigenspace doesn't changed by $T$. And your line doesn't changed. But all other points rotating. So...?

Comment: $T$ rotates the whole space $\Bbb R^3$ about some line through the origin. For instance, if the line is the $z$-axis, and $T$ is a rotation anticlockwise through $\pi/2$ radians, $T$ spins the whole space a quarter turn around the $z$-axis. Thus, the only points of $\Bbb R^3$ that are left unchanged by that rotation are the points *on* the $z$-axis. Now generalize that.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott, that helps so much!

Comment: @darocka: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let us imagine Earth and a point on it. It rotates about the axis.

A simple example of such transformation is:
$$
O_\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos \alpha & \sin\alpha \\
0 & -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now you can see that the eigenspace should be the (infinite) axis.

Comment: Without writing $A$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza OP needs intuitions.

Answer (score 0):

Let vector $\vec v$ is on line. But $T\vec v = \vec v$; so, eigenvalue is $1$ and your line is invariant subspace (and any $\vec v\ne \vec 0$ is an eigenvector).

Are there any other eigenvectors? No, all other vectors rotated by $T$, and cannot scaled.

Formally, it follows from that: rotation matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi\\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
doen't have real eigenvalues (but have complex $e^{\pm i\phi}$).

Comment: Except when $\phi=0 or 2n\pi$ n is an integer.